# Why is this screen size range wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to explain something, so I created a project for testing. I created a single-view application, set only portrait orientation (in the summary of the project) and hid the status bar (in ViewController.xib).

In `ViewController.m` I wrote one small method for detecting the point of my touch:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

In theory, I should now have a display with a width of 320 and a height of 480.

So, if I start sliding on the width, I will see values in a range of 0...320 in the command-line Here I have no problems, in practice I have values in range of 2,5 ... 317.

So, if I start sliding on height, I will see values in range of 0...480 in the command-line . But, here I where I have a problem. In practice this range is -5.5...469.

I can't understand why this is so? This range is very strange.

Comment: did you check the bounds fields of the view you are passing along to the locationInView method?

Comment: yes, i did it. bounds of this view is [320, 480]

Comment: what's the origin? for the bounds and the frame

Comment: frame of this view is (0,0,320,480) and bounds is (0,0,320,480)

Comment: which gesture recognizer are u using?

Comment: no gesture recognizer, i create a simple single-view apllication and  add only one method  - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: i see - well i try it on my machine and i don't have negative values it goes in the range of (0,0,320,460) and it is normal i have the status bar. Might be related to the way you have removed the status bar?

Comment: now i tested this with status bar, so because of changed frame view (0,20,320,480) i had new range of height is [-25.5...449]. did u test it with ios 6 and xcode 4.5?

Comment: yes ios6 and xcode 4.5.1

Comment: i tested it in simulator - not the actual device

Comment: in simulator it works great, but on device this problem appears

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to the method `locationInView`the view of your `rootViewController`. The coordinates express by this method are relative to the view you are passing.

Comment: Xcode automatiocally generate single-view project template, so this ViewController is RootViewController.